# Angular- Consume a restendpoint and then call another endpoint in the result

Tags: angular, microservices

I am new in angular and trying to learn it.

I am trying to consume a endpoint : http://localhost:9061/services

which will return below result :

```
[
"http://localhost:9001/info",
"http://localhost:9002/info",
"http://localhost9003/info",
"http://localhost:9011/info",
"http://localhost:9004/info",
"http://localhost:9005/info",
"http://localhost:9006/info"
]
```

then i need to call each endpoint of the result.

For ex -:  http://localhost:9005/info

which will return below result:

```
{
applicationName: "catlaog-service",
buildVersion: "1.0,0",
buildTimestamp: "2020-07-30T08:01:06.776Z"
}
```

Similarly , i need to call other endpoint in result and show the result in the list.

Can someone help me to how to do it angular.

This is what i tried :

```
    this.getRegisteredServices().subscribe( result => {
       this.getInfo(result)
         .subscribe((response) => {
           this.applicationName = response.applicationName;
           this.version = response.buildVersion;
           this.buildTimestamp = response.buildTimestamp;
         })
    });


 public getInfo(result): Observable<ServiceInfo> {
    return <Observable<ServiceInfo>> this.restClient.getJSON(result);
  }

  public getRegisteredServices(): Observable<any> {
    return <Observable<any>> this.restClient.getJSON(this.serviceUrl + "/services");
}

export class ServiceInfo{

  applicationName: string;
  buildVersion: string;
  buildTimestamp: string;

  constructor(applicationName: string, buildVersion: string, buildTimestamp: string) {
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
    this.buildVersion = buildVersion;
    this.buildTimestamp = buildTimestamp;
  }

  public toString() {
    return "<ServiceInfo>:[applicationName='" + this.applicationName + "'"
      + ",version:'" + this.buildVersion + "'"
      + ",buildTimestamp:'" + this.buildTimestamp + "'"
      + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please attempt to write some code first yourself. We can help you if something is not working but we're not here to write all your code

Comment: Sure i will post the code. :) . Thanks

Comment: @Mark: Added the code which i tried

Comment: Please add the definition of ServiceInfo as well. Is it an interface?

You need to iterate over the result of `getRegisteredServices` as it's an array of endpoint urls. In each iteration you call `getInfo`.

Then you need to store each result of `getInfo` in your component as a property. This should probably be an array of objects.

In your template you can then iterate over this array of objects using `*ngFor` and display the object values.

Comment: @Mark : Added the interface as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this.getInfo()` function triggers a single HTTP request for an URL, you could use RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) higher-order mapping operator to switch the response from `http://localhost:9061/services` to another observable. For the inner observable, you could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to combine multiple observables (in this case, multiple HTTP requests).

Try the following

```js
this.getRegisteredServices().pipe(
  switchMap(apps => forkJoin(apps.map(app => this.getInfo(app))))
).subscribe(
  res => this.appList = res,
  err => { }
);
```

Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is used to convert the response array from first request `['url1', 'url2', ...]` to `[this.getInfo('url1'), this.getInfo('url1'), ...]`

The output will be of the form

```js
this.appList = [
  {
    applicationName: "auth-service",
    buildVersion: "1.0,0",
    buildTimestamp: "2020-07-30T08:01:06.776Z"
  },
  {
    applicationName: "config-service",
    buildVersion: "1.0,0",
    buildTimestamp: "2020-07-30T08:01:06.776Z"
  },
  ...
]
```

#### Update: use `ServiceInfo` class from OP

You could map each request to return an object of the class `ServiceInfo`. Try the following

```js
appList: ServiceInfo[] = [];

this.getRegisteredServices().pipe(
  switchMap(apps => 
    forkJoin(apps.map(app => 
      this.getInfo(app).pipe(map(res => 
        new ServiceInfo(res['applicationName'], res['buildVersion'], res['buildTimestamp'])
      ))
    ))
  )
).subscribe(
  (res: ServiceInfo[]) => this.appList = res,
  err => { }
);
```

Comment: How you declare appList in this situtation ? appList: ServiceInfo[]; ?? @Michael D

Comment: @Stackflow: I've updated the answer to use your `ServiceInfo` class.

Comment: Getting an error : Type {} []  is not assignable to type ServiceInfo[]

Comment: @Stackflow: Try to assert the type in the subscription callback, I've updated the answer.